# Running jetty from a fatjar

Tags: java, gradle, jetty, executable-jar

I am developing a java app that starts a jetty server in the main method. This works fine when I run it in my i.d.e (STS), but when I use gradle to package this as a fatjar, the server starts, but there are no available resources. The way it behaves leads me to believe that it isn't loading the web.xml properly. 
After following a few guides, this is the method I use to start the jetty server:

```
public class JettyServer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Server server = new Server(8080);
        final WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();
        root.setContextPath("/");
        root.setDescriptor(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("web.xml")
            .getPath());
        root.setResourceBase(".");
        server.setHandler(root);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

My web.xml is in my src/main/resources, and as I say, when I run this in STS, the server starts as expected.

This is the how I have configured the jar task in gradle to build the fatjar:

```
jar{
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } } {
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }
    manifest {
       attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.main.JettyServer'
    }
}
```

When I run this, the jar gets built, and if I open the jar, I can see my web.xml file in there, but it doesn't seem to get read. What do I need to change? Am I referencing the web.xml incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup as well for a SWT based application.
Below snippet works for me:

```
 root.setDescriptor(root + "/resources/web.xml");
 root.setResourceBase(JettyServer.class.getClassLoader().getResource(WEBAPPDIR).toExternalForm());//WEBAPPDIR Directory should end with a slash
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to get this sorted and it was something so simple. Simply had to swap this line:

```
root.setDescriptor(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("web.xml")
        .getPath());
```

for this one:

```
root.setDescriptor(JettyServer.class.getResource("/WEB-INF/web.xml").toString());
```

I have accepted Mubin's answer, as they set me on the right path.

Comment: This was on point, thanks. I just switched from an external resource folder to a runnable Uber jar and needed to make this change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read something out of a JAR file, then you need to us getResourceAsStream() rather than getResource(). Here's a snippet to illustrate:

```
public class Demo 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream("stuff/myresource.xml");
        if (is != null) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                System.out.println(reader.readLine());
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You can test it out by puting a JAR on the classpath such that:

C:\dev8\stack_overflow>jar tvf stuff.jar
     0 Wed Apr 23 15:11:44 BST 2014 META-INF/
    71 Wed Apr 23 15:11:44 BST 2014 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Wed Apr 23 15:11:24 BST 2014 stuff/
    16 Wed Apr 23 15:06:40 BST 2014 stuff/myresource.xml

C:\dev8\stack_overflow>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, in this case it doesn't really apply as I need to pass a string to the setContextPath method.